# Application-defined or object- defined error with sorting a table

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i'm trying to sort data in a table i have already made. This is my code:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("PlanDataTable")
Dim so As Sort
With tbl.Sort
With .SortFields
    .Clear
    .Add Range("tbl[[#All],[PlanType]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
End With
.Header = xlYes
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.Apply
End With
```

When i get to `.Add Range("tbl[[#All],[PlanType]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending` i get the application defined error and have no idea why. Don't suppose anyone knows why

Comment: I think it's just the field for the key `Key:=Range("Table[field]")`

Comment: `tbl` has no meaning inside a range address as it's a variable. You could use `tbl.Listcolumns("PlanType")` instead of `Range("tbl[[#All],[PlanType]]")`

Comment: @Rory: `tbl.ListColumns("PlanType").Range` since SortFields.Add Key needs a range object.

Comment: @AxelRichter Oops - yes, thanks for spotting that!

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you I added the code and it worked perfectly

Comment: Thank you too @Rory